# Unable to put references from bibtex files and csl files in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to put the references as bib tex with `b-9.bib` and with some styling with `.csl` files. Both the Rmarkdown and the aforementioned files are present in the same working directory. But I am encountering this error when trying to knit to PDF.

[image: Error]

YAML Header

```
---
title: "Swarm Intelligence"
output: html_document
bibliography: b-9.bib
csl: ieee.csl
---
```

Not sure if it is because of the hyphenated naming or path issue. I even tried giving the absolute path to the header path but still the issue. or am I missing some extra code chunk or so?

Comment: Could you try to knit after renaming it to `b_9.bib`?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Is there anything like regular expression to be written for such `-` character? As far I know it is for indentation.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548948/r-markdown-could-not-find-bib-file-in-one-project-whilst-working-fine-in-anoth) answer your question?

Comment: Apparently, I posted after seeing that. That did not answer my question.

Comment: It could be your `csl` file. Could you please try changing it?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what needs to be done with the `.csl` ?

Comment: It could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62578958/13249862). Therefore, you could just remove this line `csl: ieee.csl` from your YAML header.

Comment: yes, that worked however now the generated document has no references. it shows `[WARNING] Citeproc: citation cimini2021adipose not found`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all your files have the same working directory. Also, try using "word_document" as the output format. I am not sure how your csl formatting would apply to a html document.